# Whether the set $A$ is a compact subset of $M_3(\Bbb R)$.

Tags: general-topology

> Consider $$X=\Big\{A \in M_3(\Bbb R): \rho_A(x)=x^3-3x^2+2x-1\Big\}$$ where $\rho_A(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and $M_3(\Bbb R)$ is the space of all $3 \times 3$ matrices over $\Bbb R$.
>
> Is $X$ compact in $M_3(\Bbb R)$ ?

---

My try: I confused with only the $2x$ term in $\rho_A(x)$. Because , if the $2x$ term not appear , then $X$ becomes  $$X=\{A \in M_3(\Bbb R): \text{trace}(A)=3,\det A=1\} $$ which is unbounded, since $$(\forall n \in \Bbb N):\begin{pmatrix} 1&0 & n\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix} \in X$$

But here the problem is, the appearance of $2$.  I Know  $$2=A_{11}+A_{22}+A_{33}$$

so I think in this case the set becomes bounded and closed

Any help?

Comment: I hope my earlier incorrect comment did not mislead you. The characteristic polynomial has three distinct eigenvalues, so any $A \in X$ must have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: If you were dealing with complex elements then the set $X$ would be unbounded (take an upper triangular matrix).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, 
$$ \pmatrix{t & 0 & 1\cr 1-2t & 0 & -2\cr -t^2+3t & 1 & 3-t\cr} $$
has that characteristic polynomial.  This is $S^{-1} A S$ where
$$ A = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1\cr 1 & 0 & -2\cr 0 & 1 & 3\cr},\ 
   S = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 1 & 0\cr t & 0 & 1\cr}$$

Comment: Can you shed light on how this very nice answer might have been guessed -- and whether specifying the characteristic polynomial (or some annihilating polynomial) ever yields a compact set?

Comment: @Robert Israel: super! thanks!  what is the intuition behind for finding this matrix ?

Comment: Start with a companion matrix for that characteristic polynomial.  Choose an $S$ such that $S$ and $S^{-1}$ have entries that are polynomial in $t$...

Comment: Of course there's the trivial case where the minimal polynomial has degree $1$, so the matrix is a constant multiple of $I$.

Comment: Thank you sir! :-)

Comment: @robert Israel how to choose S

Comment: Any lower triangular matrix with $1$'s on the diagonal and some entries that are non-constant polynomials in $t$ will do.

Answer (score 3):

First, observe that the given polynomial has a real root call is $\alpha$. Now the other two roots are both real or complex. If it is complex call it $\omega, \overline{\omega}$.
Consider the matrix 
$A_n= \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha& 0 & n \\
0 & 0 & |\omega|^2 \\
0& -1& 2Re \omega\\
\end{pmatrix};$ $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It's characteristic polynomial is given polynomial. If both the root are real call it $ \beta, \gamma$, then consider the matrix$ A'_n=\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha& 0 & n \\
0 & \beta & 0\\
0& 0& \gamma\\
\end{pmatrix};$ $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We get an unbounded set as $\|A_n\|\geq n$ and $\|A'_n\| \geq n$ when $ M_3(\mathbb{R})$ is identified with $\mathbb{R}^9$. I think there is nothing special about that polynomial.